# How to pass different custom requests with common Interface class?

Tags: php, laravel

Making Interface class for Crud operations I need in some cases to pass custom requests(ex. CreateTagReques)t and I make it with calling class
in  controller as :

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    try {
        \Log::info(' -1 BEFORE CreateTagRequest::');    // I see this log message
        $tag = $this->tagCrudRepository->store(
            data: $request->only('name'),
            request: new CreateTagRequest($request->all())
        );
```

that works, but validation method is not called actually, as :

I added log messages in app/Http/Requests/CreateTagRequest.php class :

```
class CreateTagRequest extends FormRequest
{
    public function authorize(): bool
    {
        return true;
    }

    public function rules(): array
    {
        $request= request();              // I DO NOT SEE THIS MESSAGE :
        \Log::info( '-1 CreateTagRequest $request->all()::' . print_r( $request->all(), true  ) );
```

and I got error:

```
: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'name' cannot be null (Connection: mysql, SQL: insert into `tags` (`name`) values (?))
```

So validation on CreateTagRequest class is not triggered. How can I trigger it ?

Problem is raised as TagCrudRepository class implements CrudInterface in app/Repositories/Interfaces/CrudInterface.php I have :

```
use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

interface CrudInterface
{
    public function store(array $data, $request): Model;
...
```

and app/Repositories/TagCrudRepository.php :

```
namespace App\Repositories;

use App\Http\Requests\CreateTagRequest;

use App\Repositories\Interfaces\CrudInterface;
class TagCrudRepository implements CrudInterface
{

    public function store(array $data, $request): Tag
    {
        ...
```

So having 1 CrudInterface for different repository classes I need to pass different custom requests and I failed in my attempt above...

How can I do it ?

Comment: Why are you trying to recreate the wheel? Don't do this. The form validation gets automatically "triggered" when the framework gets ready, so you would have to manually recreate that behaviour, a massive no. Could you explain more why are you trying to take this repository approach? I would avood it 100% and use normal controllers

Comment: Read this and the comment, it explains what I said: https://stackoverflow.com/q/76331763/1998801

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The thing I find is that on your store method you are not using formrequest.

```
Public function store(CreateTagRequest $request).
```

You interface can only receive the validated data that came after passing from CreateTagRequest.

After doing above mentioned changes you can change it to.

```
$tag = $this->tagCrudRepository->store(data: $request->validated());
```

On your interface you can change and only pass data parameter.

```
public function store(array $data)
```

Request is something which shouldn’t be handled on repository class or services class.

Comment: Which data $request>validated() have if validation failured ?